# cast from varchar to long

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, max

i need to cast from varchar(100) to bigint that way:

```
select max(cast(referencia_factura as bigint))from ventas;
```

but i get a syntax error. ¿how can i solve it?
I need to get the maximum value of the "referencia_factura" field but I need to cast it to bigint.

Comment: You could word your question better by reordering it.  Start with "Here's what I need" and then include "Here's what I tried".  Of course, what you tried should include reading the docs.  I don't use MySQL much, but it took me less than 2 minutes to determine what was wrong with your solution by skimming https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert.  I would go the route forpas recommends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is explained in [Cast Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast), casting to `BIGINT` is not supported by MySql.

I guess that `referencia_factura`'s values are too long so they can't be converted to `UNSIGNED` and also an implicit conversion like `referencia_factura + 0` would fail.

In this case what you can do is left pad the column values with `0`s up to the max length of the column which is `100` and compare them as strings to find the maximum and then trim all the leading `0`s:

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM MAX(LPAD(referencia_factura, 100, '0')))
FROM ventas;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c6684486c05800308c77fb16c454ac7).

Comment: @palanganero fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is to use implicit conversion:

```
select max(referencia_factura + 0) 
from ventas
```

Unfortunately, MySQL does not support direct conversion to `bigint`.